# Mandatory comma in the construction "...x now..."

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> The kid who grasped at straws found the hidden **path,** now submerged
> with plants of various kind.

I am wondering if a comma is necessary between path and now. Can I remove it? Are both options grammatical or not and why?

Comment: The comma is optional.

Comment: I believe it is necessary, since it reads better without it.